# How to Sort Data's in DataTable?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I am currently working with a simple project on my own using asp.net mvc3 and bootstrap.
I have this code below working perfectly. But my problem is in when displaying in my `Data Table`. As you can see in the code I `order` it by the `PositionId` and the Result in Controller is fine and but the problem is in data table.

**ID's**

> Pres - 1
>
> V. P - 2
>
> Sec - 3

**Code**

```
public JsonResult LoadTableTest()
    {
       
        var Data = new List<object>();

        Data = (from a in db.testVotings
               orderby a.PositionID
                select new
                {
                    PosId = a.PositionID,
                    testID = a.testID,
                    Fullname = a.Fullname,
                    Position = a.Position,
                    party = a.party
                }).ToList<object>();

        return Json(new
        {
            data = Data
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

**JS**

```
var dataTablestest = $("#tbltest").DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    processing: true,
    info: true,
    search: true,
    stateSave: true,
    order: [[1, "asc"]],// [2, "asc"]],
    lengthMenu: [[50, 100, 200, -1], [50, 100, 200, "All"]],
    ajax: { "url": "/Voting/LoadTableTest" },
    columns:
    [
    { data: "PosId", title: "", orderable: true ,visible: false, searchable: false },
         { data: "testID", title: "",orderable: false, visible: false, searchable: false },
        { data: "Fullname", title: "FullName",orderable: false, sClass: "alignRight" },
        { data: "Position", title: "Position",orderable: false, sClass: "alignRight" },
        { data: "party", title: "Party",orderable: false, sClass: "alignRight" },
        { data: "ActionMenu", title: "Click to vote", searchable: false, orderable: false, sClass: "alignCenter",
            "mRender": function (data) {
                return '<center><label><input class="checkId" type="checkbox" /></label></center>';
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

**HTML**

```
 < table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive nowrap" role="grid" style="width: 100%;" id="tbltest">
 < /table>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: show your view/source code.

Comment: Look at your tag `datatable`, you'll see that it's ambigous. So you need to clarify to what kind of `DataTable` you are referring to.

Comment: @SorangwalaAbbasali done. >Tim Sorry About it.

Comment: @KiRa: **Read this please**
**Please be aware that order() method sets the ordering to apply to the table - it does not actually perform the order. In order to have the order performed, use the draw() method, which can be called simply as a chained method of the order() method's returned object - for example table.order([0, 'desc']).draw();.**

Comment: @SorangwalaAbbasali can I use that in my code?. How?